# Como obter o header X-Forwarded-For (IP) pelo passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, passport-js

Estou utilizando [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) para criar rota para minha aplicação. Para login eu tenho uma rota para autenticar utilizando [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) e [passport-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local). Preciso comparar o IP de acesso do usuário com o IP do usuário que foi registrado.

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/index',
    failureRedirect: '/login?fail=true'
}))
```

No meu arquivo `auth.js` eu tenho isso ...

```
module.exports = passport => {
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    (req, username, password, done) => {
        console.log(req.headers)
        findUser(username, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return done(err)
            if (!user) return done(null, false)

            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isValid) => {
                if (err) return done(err)
                if (!isValid) return done(null, false)
                return done(null, user)
            })
        })
    })
)}
```

No `express` é possível obter o `header` da requisição feita na rota usando o primeiro parâmetro do callback `request.headers['x-forwarded-for']` mas no passport,  no retorno de  `request.headers['x-forwarded-for']` é `undefined`, então eu verifiquei que não tem o header `x-forwarded-for` na requisição do passport. Como posso conseguir obte-lo?